# matplotlib: save fig with bbox_inches='tight' ignores annotation

Tags: python, matplotlib

It appears that the `bbox_inches='tight'` option in `savefig` ignores annotations without text.  Here is my example code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6])
arrow1 = ax.annotate('text', xy = [0.5,-0.2], xycoords = 'axes fraction', \
    xytext = [-72,0], textcoords = 'offset points', \
    arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '-|>', mutation_scale = 10.0, \
    shrinkA = 0, shrinkB = 0, linewidth = 1))
arrow2 = ax.annotate('', xy = [0.5,1.2], xycoords = 'axes fraction', \
    xytext = [-72,0], textcoords = 'offset points', \
    arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '-|>', mutation_scale = 10.0, \
    shrinkA = 0, shrinkB = 0, linewidth = 1))
fig.savefig('test.png')
fig.savefig('test-tight.png', bbox_inches = 'tight')
```

Here is `test.png`, showing that I have two annotations.  One annotation, with text, below the axes and one annotation, without text, above the axes.

[image]

Here is `test-tight.png`, showing only one annotation.  The annotation above the axes, without the text, has been ignored.

[image]

Looking in the source code, `bbox_inches='tight'` attempts to find the size and location of artists by calling `artist.get_window_extent()`.  When I try `arrow1.get_window_extent()`, I get a bounding box that appears to correspond to the text.  When I try `arrow2.get_window_extent()`, I get a bounding box with zero height and zero width.  Thus, the root of the problem is `.get_window_extent()` doesn't include the arrow.

Any ideas for how to get around this, in a reasonably robust manner?  If I could somehow get the proper bounding box for the whole annotation, then I would be in business.  However, I can't even seem to get the line or patch objects out of `arrow2`.

In case it matters, I am on matplotlib 1.4.0, Python 2.7.6, and Mac OS X 10.8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually reported this bug as [issue 3816](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3816/) back in 2014, and it was fixed in matplotlib v1.4.3.  Sorry for not posting this result earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try creating a bounding box by adding the following argument to your annotation command: `bbox=dict(facecolor='none', edgecolor='none', pad=1.0)`
or you try if the bounding box is automatically created if you add some spaces or white characters.